# Getting and using returned variables from a Method to a Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I currently have a model that creates an array and returns it using the following:

```
$data = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'slug' => $slug,
    'text' => $this->input->post('text')
);

$this->db->insert('table-name', $data);
$id = $this->db->insert_id();

return $data;
```

Unfortunately the variable $data is empty when I get it back in my controller. How do I go about getting hold of this data to pass to my view.

Comment: The issue I was having was because you don't use the array $data directly in CodeIgniter. Instead it automatically makes everything inside accessible directly as opposed to through the $data array. For example if your $data array had an array inside called 'item'. You would simply call $item['title'], as opposed to $data['item']['title']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems fine.

Controller:

```
$data['mydata'] = $this->my_model->my_method();
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

View

```
<?= $mydata ?>
```